# Android translating date depending on Locale

Tags: android, date, locale

I can"t get to work a simple code in a fresh project that is suppose to simply write one date in many langage depending on the Locale set.

```
Locale[] locales = new Locale[] {
            Locale.JAPAN,
            Locale.CHINA,
            Locale.KOREA,
            Locale.TAIWAN,
            Locale.ITALY,
            Locale.FRANCE,
            Locale.GERMAN
    };

    // Get an instance of current date time
    Date today = new Date();

    //
    // Iterates the entire Locale defined above and create a long 
    // formatted date using the SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance() 
    // with the format, the Locale and the date information.
    //
    for (Locale locale : locales) {
        System.out.println("Date format in "
            + locale.getDisplayName() 
            + " = "
            + SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(
                  SimpleDateFormat.LONG, locale)
                      .format(today).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Here is the link of this code : [URL of the code below](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/415.html)

Now here is what it's suppose to display

Date format in Japanese (Japan) = 2009/01/04

Date format in Chinese (China) = 2009年1月4日

Date format in Korean (South Korea) = 2009년 1월 4일 (일)

Date format in Chinese (Taiwan) = 2009年1月4日

Date format in Italian (Italy) = 4 GENNAIO 2009

Date format in French (France) = 4 JANVIER 2009

Date format in German = 4. JANUAR 2009

And here is MY display :

Date format in Japanese (Japan) = 2012 7 21

Date format in Chinese (China) = 2012 7 21

Date format in Korean (South Korea) = 2012 7 21

Date format in Chinese (Taiwan) = 2012 7 21

Date format in Italian (Italy) = 2012 7 21

Date format in French (France) = 2012 7 21

Date format in German = 2012 7 21

**PROBLEM** : What's wrong ? Am I forgeting some obvious thing ? Do you have any lead ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you test it on multiple devices? Do they always output the same thing? It's weird, your code looks ok. I use `DateFormat` instead of `SimpleDateFormat` (the methods are the same here) and it works for me

Comment: I tried on only one device, HTC Desire when I'm currently in China, but I don't see in what this is related (if you can tell me). I tried also DateFormat instead of SimpleDateFormat, but as you excpected nothing changed.

Comment: I thought that it might be some bug in the device, because locale settings are stored in the system, I think. Try emulator and also try using different format, SHORT or FULL. Also it's rather common to use `Log.d()` instead of `System.out.println()`, but I don't think that it would change anything

Comment: Ok "Problem solved".... I'm just wondering now how can I do to display a date depending on the Localisation if devices aren't able  to use them ...

Comment: By solved you mean that it works on emulator? See this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9453. On my desire it works but it's a custom 2.3.7 MIUI ROM.

Comment: Yes it works on the emulator. There is something else weird. On my HTC, I can choose language between english, chinese and thai. Chinese and thai won't work. The question is : why ? the device offer it, it should be able to translate ... Anyway I'll find a workaround, the point is the translation is suppose to work on some devices (and worked on emulator). Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out it's a device-specific problem. The code works on a phone with correct locale data and also on emulator. On HTC Desire there are some ROMs which have locale data corrupted. [More on this issue.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9453)